# How to run updatedb as a cron job?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I see multiple questions that are answered with `crontab -e; 0 24 * * * updatedb` but that is failing for me.

Updatedb cannot be run as a normal user, it must be run as root. So how does this cronjob complete successfully? I get a daily email with the error:

```
updatedb: can not change group of file `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.1ms8PJ' to `mlocate': Operation not permitted
```

This is after a `chmod -R a+w /var/lib/mlocate` so that cron can access the files, but it doesn't look like it can.

I really don't understand how this is working for everyone else. I've never, across many machines, been able to run `updatedb` as any user other than root.

Comment: Is your question how to run it as a cron job or how to run it not as root?  The answer to the first one answers itself if you run it as root.  Everyone is doing it like that.  What is the original problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: How do I put a sudo in a cron job? would that not wait for a password?

Comment: It won't if you have your sudoers set up not to prompt one.. but why not just put it in root's crontab?  Why do you want to use sudo?

Comment: > Put it in root's crontab... duh, thank you

Comment: On most Linux distributions it already has its own cron job, or on _modern_ systems, a systemd timer. It's not likely you need to do anything. What you should do instead is to start over by explaining [the _real_ problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) that led you to this (wrong) solution in the first place.